# JpaSpecificationExecutor.findAll(Specification arg0, Pageable arg1) returns duplicates

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

We are using org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor.findAll(Specification arg0, Pageable arg1) from spring-data-jpa-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar.
Fetch size 1000 has been set in PageRequest.
We have more than 60000 records for in database view.
Single Customer can have n number of records.
It means that it will the entire data in 60 fetches.
If a customer data is picked in one read, then we are good.

Row Customer

*********************** CASE 1

998 Customer A

999 Customer A

1000 Customer A

*********************** Page End

1001 Customer B

1002 Customer B

Else if customer data is spread in two reads then we are getting into serious problem

Row Customer
*********************** CASE 2

998  Customer X

999  Customer X

1000 Customer X

**********************Page End -

1001 Customer X

1002 Customer X

In this case Customer X s record is not consistent with the database. We can see duplicate records for X customer, it means Some of the original rows of Customer X is missing.
we get duplicate of existing rows from page.getContent(). But the overall count of the Customer X always remains same.

The issue does not happen when there is no overlap as in Case 1, and a direct read from database using sql developer always gives the correct rows.
There was additional sorting also provided in the code, but removed the sort and checked and the result was still the same.
However, if the number of rows read is increased to a very large value i.e 30000, which means that there are only 2 reads, there are only duplciates for the customer that overlaps between page 30 and 31.
If there is less data in database (300 rows) then also no problem found even if the customer is speard in 2 reads. 
Its a little bit confusing for me pls give me some hints.

Answer (score 1):

Use `query.distinct(true)` in your `toPredicate` method in your Specification. Then it will fetch distinct results only.

Example:

```
public class CustomSpecification implements Specification<MyObject> {

        private MyCriteria criteria;

        public CustomSpecification(MyCriteria criteria) {
            this.criteria = criteria;
        }

        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<MyObject> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
            Predicate myPredicate =...;
            query.distinct(true);
            return myPredicate;
        }
    }
```